# Fade out if mouse does not hover element

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

Basically I want to fade out an element if after x seconds there is no mouseover event triggered. I've tried for a few hours and just can't seem to write the code to work properly.

So far I've written -

```
$('.toolTip').live('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true).fadeIn();
});
$('.toolTip').live('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).delay(4000).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Which works if the mouse enters the div, and then leaves, but not if it doesn't ever gain focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be to add a `fadeTo()` command in addition to your mouseover events so that it initially begins fading out:

```
$(".toolTip").delay(1000).fadeTo(5000, 0);
$(".toolTip").on({
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).delay(1000).fadeTo(5000, 0);
    },
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo(500, 1);
    }
});
```

​
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Snowsickle/FFPWp/)

Comment: Thank you, Alex, just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 5):

The `mouseover` event will never be called on the .toolTip div because `fadeOut()` will finish by applying `display:none` to the element, thus preventing you from ever mousing over it again. Instead of fadeOut(), you can use fadeTo() to change it's opacity without affecting it's display property.

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.toolTip', function() {
    $(this).stop().fadeTo("fast", 1);
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '.toolTip', function() {
    $(this).delay(4000).fadeTo("slow", 0);
});​
```

Comment: Sorry Derek, I don't think I explained it well. If the mouse **doesn't** enter the toolTip element to fade it out then. But obviously stop and turn opacity back to 100% if hovered during the fade out.

Comment: Fair enough, but my original statement still stands. It wasn't working because fadeOut() would completely hide it and prevent any future mouseovers. Not sure how that differs from the answer you accepted.

Comment: Sorry, the `$(".toolTip").delay(1000).fadeTo(5000, 0);` was what I was looking to achieve, to just fade out an element after a period of time of it never being hovered or interacted with. I was trying to trigger that with a timer, but obviously it was a silly mistake. Thank you for the advice on `fadeOut()` ! It did explain another one of my silly mistakes! Thankyou @Derek